# Bootstrap DatePicker to allow editing through typing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, coffeescript

In my current project I am using the Bootstrap datepicker to allow users to select dates.

There has been a request to allow people to type the date into the datePicker input rather than having to manually click on the dates in the widget.

Currently when a user manually edits the date string, the date picker will highlight the correct day, but it will not update the variable it is assigned to.  (As a note I am using Knockout.js and using an observable for storing the date)

My thoughts were that this would simply trigger the changeDate function but it does not.

Has anyone ever tried to achieve this and get it working?

Comment: I have achieved this by creating two separate binding handlers. One to bind the input to the date observable and one to bind the datepicker. It looks like that.  
`<div class="input-append date" >  
    <input type="text" data-bind="dateValue: date">  
    <span class="add-on datepicker-button"
        data-bind="datePicker: { date: date, options: { todayHighlight: true } }">  
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>  
    </span>  
</div>`

Comment: I'm refreining from posting code as it is written in a specific architecture and cannot be copy/pasted. If you want i can extract the bindings as an answer.

Comment: I really think you should post your solution as an answer . It will be valuable for the community for sure .

Comment: @AngelYordanov even just posting a very trimmed down, even almost pseudocode method would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angelyordanov/PJHxD/) and a [gist](https://gist.github.com/angelyordanov/4730076) of the `datePicker` and `dateValue` bindings, which bind independently to an observable and update it accordingly.

```html
<div class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" data-bind="dateValue: date" />
    <span class="add-on datepicker-button" data-bind="datePicker: { date: date }">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

The bindings are written with a `BindingHandlerFactory` wrapper that
 1. creates a handler object for each element bound and stores it with `$.data()` on the element.
 2. calls the handler's `initialize(element, context)` once.
 3. call the handler's `contextChanged(context)` method every time the binding context changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not use not Read/Write options with KO.

something like

```
function yourModel(){
var self = this;
self.theDateUserManuallyWillEnter = ko.computed({
read: function () {
    if (self.theDateUserManuallyWillEnter != undefined)
        return self.theDateUserManuallyWillEnter ;
    else
        return $('#theDateUserManuallyWillEnteredTextBox').val(); //Jquery      
                                 identifier of text box
},
write: function (value) {
    self.theDateUserManuallyWillEnter = value;
},
owner: this
});
}
```